# Python openCV video recording not in true time

Tags: python, opencv

Trying to record "time true" video with openCV. When recording video footage it seems to be slightly sped up. If I hold a timer up to the webcam and then play it back saved footage is 3 - 5 seconds too fast per minute of saved footage.

How can I get the saved video to be exactly 1 minute if I record 1 minute from my webcam? Or  2 minutes of recording to be an exported 2-minute video?

```
import cv2
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

width  = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)   # float `width`
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)  # float `height`

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter('MYPATH\\video.avi', fourcc, fps, (int(width),int(height)))
 
while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('video', frame)
        videoWriter.write(frame)
 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
 
cap.release()
videoWriter.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: don't expect the camera to give you frames at the _precise_ frame rate that you requested (or it reports). webcams can adapt their own frame rate to lighting conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why this fixed it... but changing the forcc to fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V') and then changing the output file from .avi to .mp4 fixed the problem.

Comment: I would reeeally love to know why this works. This solved *not only* this problem for me of the timing being off (which I'd labored to solve on my own with a janky solution I didn't like), but it also solved another issue of the video file randomly stopping after a few minutes. With mp4v and .mp4 I seem to be able to record however long I want in a multithreaded solution at least, and not only does it work, the timing is spot on now without any other intervention

Answer (score 0):

Your program may write additional frames because `True` sentence at line **16** in your `while` *loop*, then change that value to check as conditional `ret`, by:

```
...
ret, frame = cap.read()
while (ret):    
    cv2.imshow('video', frame)
    videoWriter.write(frame)
 
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
videoWriter.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: no, that's not it. as you can see in the question's code, only successfully read frames are written to the output file. -- it is also wrong to duplicate the `cap.read()`. a `while True:` is perfectly acceptable here. however, `if not ret: break` would be advisable

Comment: very good, I see that it is a real problem since I have not executed the code, although with the correction that you have made I do not understand how I would interpret it: *'2 minutes of recording to be an exported 2-minute video'*